# wordpress allow admin to edit user profile with custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields, user-profile

I am trying to customize a Wordpress site user's profile with some custom fields. The custom fields should then display on the front-end.
I've managed to display the fields on the user admin dashboard to allow the site admin to make updates.

Problem 1: However, the updates are not saving in the dashboard after saving the profile.

Problem 2: The updated fields are not displaying on the front-end in the user profile.

Here's the code I have in my child-theme's functions.php:

```
//add field for editing on user profile

/**
 *  @param $user
 *  @author Webkul edited by Wano
 */

// add_action('show_user_profile', 'wk_custom_user_profile_fields');
add_action('edit_user_profile', 'wk_custom_user_profile_fields');

function wk_custom_user_profile_fields($user)
{
    echo '<h3 class="heading">Custom Fields</h3>';

?>

    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="due">Amount Due</label></th>

            <td><input type="text" class="input-text form-control" name="due" id="due" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><label for="status">Payment Status</label></th>

            <td>
                <select id="status" name="status" size="">
                    <option value="pending">Pending</option>
                    <option value="approved">Approved</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><label for="received">Payment received</label></th>

            <td><input type="text" class="input-text form-control" name="received" id="received" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

<?php
}
```

Here's what it looks like in the dashboard. All good so far.

[image]

Then I'm saving the fields here.

```
//Save custom user profile meta data fields
//add_action('personal_options_update', 'wk_save_custom_user_profile_fields');
add_action('edit_user_profile_update', 'wk_save_custom_user_profile_fields');

/**
 *   @param User Id $user_id
 */
function wk_save_custom_user_profile_fields($user_id)
{

    // $custom_data = $_POST['due'];
    // update_user_meta($user_id, 'due', $custom_data);

    if (!current_user_can('edit_user', $user_id)) {
        return false;
    }
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'due', $_POST['due']);
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'status', $_POST['status']);
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'received', $_POST['received']);
}

?>
```

And then the fields don't show up on the front-end. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is a screenshot of the profile page called dashboard.php. My custom code is between the comments //Code by Wayne.

What I'm displaying is the logged in users username and then below I intend to display the custom fields $due, $status and $received. I'm including custom-code.php for the code.

[image]

Here's what I've have in custom-code.php to display the fields which is obviously very wrong.

```
<?php 
    do_action('wk_custom_user_profile_fields', $due);
    do_action('wk_custom_user_profile_fields', $status);
    do_action('wk_custom_user_profile_fields', $received);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like logic is right.

Probably, fetching values to your `HTML` template could solve the problem

```
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'wk_custom_user_profile_fields' );

function wk_custom_user_profile_fields( $user ) {
    $due      = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'due', true );
    $status   = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'status', true );
    $received = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'received', true );

    echo '<h3 class="heading">Custom Fields</h3>';

    ?>

    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="due">Amount Due</label></th>

            <td><input type="text" class="input-text form-control" name="due" id="due" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $due ) ?>"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><label for="status">Payment Status</label></th>

            <td>
                <select id="status" name="status" size="">
                    <option value="pending" <?php selected( $status, 'pending' ) ?>>Pending</option>
                    <option value="approved" <?php selected( $status, 'approved' ) ?>>Approved</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><label for="received">Payment received</label></th>

            <td><input type="text" class="input-text form-control" name="received" id="received" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $received ) ?>"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <?php
}
```

I think, showing fields without `do_action` could solve the problem

`custom-code.php` content:

```
<?php

    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return;
    }
    
    $due      = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'due', true );
    $status   = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'status', true );
    $received = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'received', true );
    
    echo esc_html( $due );
    echo esc_html( $status );
    echo esc_html( $received );
```

Comment: Awesome Thank you, that has solve the first problem of the forms not updating on the back-end. Now the values are saving in the admin dashboard. Now I just need to get those values displayed on the front-end.

Comment: i don't think they will magically appear; you likely will have to add these to an action.

Comment: @WayneRHendricks, please take a screenshot or give PHP snippet of the user template file or specify the theme name you use. Then I could help to detect the reason for problem 2

Comment: Thanks @Andril Kovalenko. I'm using a theme called Kadence and an affiliate  plugin calling Affiliates. The Affiliates plugin calls a dashboard.php file which is the user profile page. I've included a custom.php file for the action, but I don't know how to call the action.

Comment: I have updated the question with the dashboard.php template

Comment: Awesome Thank you @AndriiKovalenko. That did the trick.